# String pattern alteration

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have a function that could do the following

ex:
      '1100001' ->breaking into two parts 1::2 and 0::2-> and join it to get '1001001'. how to get the original string '1100001' from the output

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new list of the same length of the original one and assign corresponding elements to it:

```
s = '1001001'

s1 = list(s)
s1[1::2], s1[0::2] = s[:(len(s) // 2)], s[(len(s) // 2):]

''.join(s1)
# '1100001'
```

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition, accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Comment: i did that already as i don't have enough points its not showing up